# MATLAB Changing matrix elements

Tags: matlab

How can I iterate over matrix and change values under condition.. for e.g:
I have matrix m with size 100x100 and Im doing:

```
m(m<10)=func(elemnt);
```

element should be the current element at iteration.. How do I access the current element??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try simply
`m(m<10)=func(m(m<10));`

example:

```
m=[[1 2 3];[5 6 7];[8 9 10]]

m =
1    2    3
5    6    7
8    9   10

m(mod(m,3)==2) = m(mod(m,3)==2) * 5
m =
 1   10    3
25    6    7
40    9   10
```

The only constraint is that your custom function can handle vectors.

Comment: thanks its working.. But if i'm doing something like:
m(m<10)=func(m(m<10));
m(m>=10)=func(m(m>=10));
will it run all over the matrix twice???

Comment: You can cache the temporary: `c=m<10; m(c) = func(m(c));`, but not the expression `m(c)`, as that expression is evaluated both from the left side and from the right side: it's both read from and written into.

Comment: you should temporarily cache `c=m<10;` because you change the values and might not want to re-calculate the constraint on the changed values (`m(ii)` might be `<10` and after applying `func`, it might be `>10`)